# AWK: Edit values in columns when a pattern is met

Tags: awk

I have a tab separated csv file with 3500 lines. On this file, I have to edit the values in columns 5 and 6, depending on the values of columns 3, 4 and 5.

Rules:

We just have to edit lines where the value in column 5 does not exceed "3500".

As you can see the value in column 6 is the concanetacion of columns 5 and 7.

If the values in columns 3 and 4 are:

```
"AR" "ES" => add 10000 to the value in column 5.
"BE" "FR" => add 20000 to the value in column 5.
"BE" "NL" => add 30000 to the value in column 5.
"BR" "PT" => add 40000 to the value in column 5.
"DK" "DA" => add 50000 to the value in column 5.
```

The file contains

```
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "AR"    "ES"    "100"   "100reto"   "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "AR"    "ES"    "11"    "11reto"    "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "AR"    "ES"    "9654236"   "9654236expe"   "expe"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BE"    "FR"    "1078"  "1078reto"  "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460652" "027460652expe" "expe"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460652" "027460652reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BR"    "PT"    "1045"  "1045reto"  "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BR"    "PT"    "1046"  "1046reto"  "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BR"    "PT"    "1094"  "1094reto"  "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "DK"    "DA"    "017187074" "017187074reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "DK"    "DA"    "017187090" "017187090reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "DK"    "DA"    "384"   "384reto"   "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "DK"    "DA"    "387"   "387reto"   "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "1019"  "1019reto"  "reto"
```

Expected output:

```
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "AR"    "ES"    "10100" "10100reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "AR"    "ES"    "10011" "10011reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "AR"    "ES"    "9654236"   "9654236expe"   "expe"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BE"    "FR"    "21078" "21078reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460652" "027460652expe" "expe"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460652" "027460652reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BR"    "PT"    "41045" "41045reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BR"    "PT"    "41046" "41046reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BR"    "PT"    "41094" "41094reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "DK"    "DA"    "017187074" "017187074reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "DK"    "DA"    "017187090" "017187090reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "DK"    "DA"    "50384" "50384reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "DK"    "DA"    "50387" "50387reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"    "NL"    "301019"    "301019reto"    "reto"
```

Comment: You says it's a CSV but there's no commas in your sample input. You tell us the file contains "something like".... Don't do show us something that's not what you actually want to process or you'll get an answer that doesn't do what you want to do. Edit your question to clean it up and provide concrete, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot...

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
        to_add["\"AR\"" "\"ES\""] = 10000
        to_add["\"BE\"" "\"FR\""] = 20000
        to_add["\"BE\"" "\"NL\""] = 30000
        to_add["\"BR\"" "\"PT\""] = 40000
        to_add["\"DK\"" "\"DA\""] = 50000
        OFS = "   "
    }

    {
        split($5, num, "\"")
    }

num[2] > 3500   {
        print
    }

num[2] <= 3500 {
        split($7, cat, "\"")
        $5 = num[2] + to_add[$3 $4]
        $6 = "\"" $5 cat[2] "\""
        $5 = "\"" $5 "\""
        $5 = $5
        print
    }
```

I'm not sure if the spacing in your file is essential, so I've made no particular attempt to preserve it, just setting everything to 3 spaces.  The output is:

```
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "AR"   "ES"   "10100"   "10100reto"   "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "AR"   "ES"   "10011"   "10011reto"   "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "AR"    "ES"    "9654236"   "9654236expe"   "expe"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BE"   "FR"   "21078"   "21078reto"   "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460652" "027460652expe" "expe"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BE"    "NL"    "027460652" "027460652reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BR"   "PT"   "41045"   "41045reto"   "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BR"   "PT"   "41046"   "41046reto"   "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "BR"   "PT"   "41094"   "41094reto"   "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "DK"    "DA"    "017187074" "017187074reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QSA"   "DK"    "DA"    "017187090" "017187090reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "DK"   "DA"   "50384"   "50384reto"   "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "DK"   "DA"   "50387"   "50387reto"   "reto"
voc_sales_ren   "QVN"   "BE"   "NL"   "31019"   "31019reto"   "reto"
```

Here's the deal:

1. First, it sets up the values that you want to add in the `BEGIN` clause.  They're in an array that will be referenced later.
2. It splits field 5 on the double-quote character.  This is a cheap and easy way to strip off the quotes.
3. If the numeric values of field 5 is less than or equal to 3500, it performs the changes you wanted.  To do this it (a) strips off the quotes from $7, (b) adds to $5 the value set up in `BEGIN` corresponding to $3 and $4, (c) prepends a double quote and the new value of $5 to the alphabetic part of $7, (d) puts new quotes onto the new value of $5, and (e) rebuilds the line and prints.
4. If greater than 3500, just print the line.

Answer (score 0):

awk in this way?

a file name `awk_script` with these codes

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
#store all codes in an array
BEGIN{ar["ARES"]=10000;ar["BEFR"]=20000;ar["BENL"]=30000;ar["BRPT"]=40000;ar["DKDA"]=50000} 
{gsub(/["]/,"",$0) # take out all quotes, we will put them back
if(($3 $4 in ar)){   #test to see if column 3 and 4 match your array codes
    $5=$5+ar[$3$4];
    gsub(/^[0-9]+/,$5,$6); 
 };
for(i=2;i<=NF;++i){  #add back you quotes
    $i=qt $i qt};print
}
```

run script like

```
awk -v qt='"' -f awk_script
```

Your expected output

```
voc_sales_ren "QSA" "AR" "ES" "10100" "10100reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren "QSA" "AR" "ES" "10011" "10011reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren "QSA" "AR" "ES" "9664236" "9664236expe" "expe"
voc_sales_ren "QSA" "BE" "FR" "21078" "21078reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren "QSA" "BE" "NL" "27490652" "27490652expe" "expe"
voc_sales_ren "QSA" "BE" "NL" "27490652" "27490652reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren "QSA" "BR" "PT" "41045" "41045reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren "QSA" "BR" "PT" "41046" "41046reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren "QSA" "BR" "PT" "41094" "41094reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren "QSA" "DK" "DA" "17237074" "17237074reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren "QSA" "DK" "DA" "17237090" "17237090reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren "QVN" "DK" "DA" "50384" "50384reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren "QVN" "DK" "DA" "50387" "50387reto" "reto"
voc_sales_ren "QVN" "BE" "NL" "31019" "31019reto" "reto"
```

Comment: It appears that field 6 does not match the expected output.